# CXF JAXRS - http-conf:client ReceiveTimeout does not work?

Tags: apache, cxf, jax-rs

My client's spring context:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:authorization>
        <sec:AuthorizationType>Negotiate</sec:AuthorizationType>
    </http-conf:authorization>
    <http-conf:client ReceiveTimeout="0"></http-conf:client>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

Server continues to process the request, but the client times out after 60000ms, which is the default timeout value. Any help?

**Update (Apr 10, 2012):**

Tried the following approach.

```
    ClientProxyImpl client = (ClientProxyImpl) alertService;
    Client proxy = ClientProxy.getClient(alertService);

    HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) proxy.getConduit();

    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
    httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(60000);

    conduit.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

Got the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(ClientProxy.java:120)
```

Appreciate any help to get this working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="http://hostname.com/.*">
```

To see if it is picked up that way.   Rest doesn't really have a concept of endpoint names and such like JAX-WS does so it may not be able to match on that.

Comment: That didn't help. Found a couple of such instances on cxf-user mailing list and apparently setting this programmatically is the way around. Trying that right now, but mixing spring & non-spring versions is a pain and requires re-factoring things a bit. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Daniel, tried programmatic approach but I guess I'm missing something or it only works with jax-ws and not jax-rs. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the original post with more details.